# center <li> elements in <ul> depending on <li> size

Tags: css, positioning, centering

[image]

In the image above, you can see that -its not perfect- all the `<ul>` elements have all the same size, and the `<li>` items no, but they are centered in the `<ul>` no matter what size is (always assuming that will be smaller)

how can i do this?

```
ul{ width:160px; }
li{ width:auto; margin:5px auto;}
```

is not working..

-Image edited with texts-

[image: some text for the]

Comment: You can't use margin: auto when your width is undefined. Why can't you use li{ text-align: center; width: 100%; }?

Comment: you can see in my edit, i need text-align:left :(

Comment: What is the problem/what do you actually want to happen? Do you *want* to get the appearance in the first image?

Comment: I think your problem mainly comes from the fact that there is no such thing as your brown box. You should consider wrapping you <ul> elements in another box (ul becoming the brown box, the wrapper being the red one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to say with your images, but here's how to make something that looks like them.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wGpPc/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        ..
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.listContainer {
    width: 160px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 9px
}
.listContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    background: #f0f;

    /* for ie6/7 */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
li {
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: #fff
}
```